# Nginx - forward requests according to host names

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

DNS translate example.com to my frontends's IP.

Now I want to configure Nginx in a way that the traffic gets redirected to IP's according to the requested hostname.

So the frontend is available under example.com.
A request for (e.g.) webmail.example.com should be forwarded to 192.168.0.**1**:80.
A request for calendar.example.com should be forwarded to 192.168.0.**2**:80,
and a request for mywiki.example.com shall be forwarded to 192.168.0.**3**:443

Comment: You will have to create seperate server blocks for each of the hostnames you need.

Comment: hm ... like:  
    server {
       listen 80;
       server_name webmail.example.com;
       location / {
        proxy_pass 192.168.0.1;
      }
    }
    server {
      listen 80;
      server_name calendar.example.com;
      location / {
        proxy_pass 192.168.0.2;
      }
    }
   ..